# C# RabbitMQ pool/queue approach

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, blockingcollection

I'm trying to create a queue/pool of rabbit mq channels for reuse, which they recommend to do this, but don't provide any approach of how to actually do this!

I have this working but ideally I don't want to populate the channels when the constructor is called. I would like to create up to 9 channels only creating one when one is required.

I want to remove the following from the full example shown.

```
// COMMENT THIS LINE OUT
GetConnection();

// COMMENT THESE LINE OUT
for (var i = 0; i < MAX_CHANNELS; i++)
{
    _channelQueue.Add(_connection.CreateModel());
     _channelCount++;
}
// END
```

When I do remove these, the first time of creating a channel and or connection takes **13 seconds**, but this doesn't happen if I leave the code in! This is quite confusing for me and i'm not sure what is going on now.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Diagnostics;
using RabbitMQ.Client;

namespace Enqueue
{
    public class RabbitMqChannelPool
    {
        private readonly string _hostName;

        private const int MAX_CHANNELS = 9;
        
        // Keep track of the number of good channels
        private int _channelCount = 0;

        private IConnection _connection;
        
        private readonly BlockingCollection<IModel> _channelQueue = new BlockingCollection<IModel>(MAX_CHANNELS);

        private Object connectionLock = new Object();
        private Object channelLock = new Object();

        public RabbitMqChannelPool(string hostName)
        {
            _hostName = hostName;
            // COMMENT THIS LINE OUT
            GetConnection();
        }
        
        private IConnection GetConnection()
        {
            lock (connectionLock)
            {
                if (_connection == null || !_connection.IsOpen)
                {
                    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
                    sw.Start();
                    _connection = CreateNewConnection();
                    // Having this here makes it run fast, creating on the fly seems to block for ages on the first one
                    // COMMENT THESE LINE OUT
                    for (var i = 0; i < MAX_CHANNELS; i++)
                    {
                        _channelQueue.Add(_connection.CreateModel());
                        _channelCount++;
                    }
                    // END
                    sw.Stop();
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Connection created in { sw.Elapsed.Seconds}.{sw.Elapsed.Milliseconds} seconds");
                }
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Returning Connection");
                return _connection;
            }
        }

        private IConnection CreateNewConnection()
        {
            var factory = new ConnectionFactory
            {
                HostName = _hostName
            };

            return factory.CreateConnection();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get a channel if at all possible
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public IModel DequeueChannel()
        {
            lock (channelLock)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Getting channel from queue");
                // if we have not used up the limit then return one
                // This should then be put back on the queue after use
                if (_channelCount < MAX_CHANNELS)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Returning new channel");
                    return CreateNewChannel();
                }

                // Otherwise block until one becomes available
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Waiting for queue...");
                IModel channel = _channelQueue.Take(); // this blocks till there is something there
                return channel;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Add the channel back on the queue if it seems fine
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="channel"></param>
        public void EnqueueChannel(IModel channel)
        {
            if (channel != null && channel.IsOpen)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Putting channel back on queue");
                _channelQueue.Add(channel);
            }
            else
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Channel was bad");
                _channelCount--;
            }
        }

        private IModel CreateNewChannel()
        {
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            var channel = GetConnection().CreateModel();
            sw.Stop();
            _channelCount++;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Channel {_channelCount} created in { sw.Elapsed.Seconds}.{sw.Elapsed.Milliseconds} seconds");
            return channel;
        }

        public int ChannelQueueSize => _channelCount;
    }
}
```

I have this unit test to try and simulate it being called in quick succession.

```
[SetUp]
public void Setup()
{
    _rabbitMqChannel = new RabbitMqChannelPool("localhost");
}

[Test]
public void WhenMoreChannelsRequestedThanAvailable_ThenBlockAndWaitTillAvailable()
{
    // Arrange
    // Act

    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

    for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(DoSomeWork));
    }

    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

    // Assert

    Assert.AreEqual(9, _rabbitMqChannel.ChannelQueueSize);
}

private void DoSomeWork()
{
    var channel = _rabbitMqChannel.DequeueChannel();
    Thread.Sleep(100); // simulate doing some work
    _rabbitMqChannel.EnqueueChannel(channel);
}
```

When I run this in debug unit test mode I can see the output as follows as you can see it says 13.816 seconds but if I leave the code in for it to initially populate the queue then it runs fast?

```
Getting channel from queue
Returning new channel
Connection created in 13.861 seconds
Returning Connection
Channel 1 created in 13.876 seconds
Getting channel from queue
Returning new channel
Returning Connection
Channel 2 created in 0.2 seconds
Getting channel from queue
Returning new channel
Returning Connection
Channel 3 created in 0.3 seconds
Getting channel from queue
Returning new channel
Returning Connection
Channel 4 created in 0.3 seconds
Getting channel from queue
Returning new channel
Returning Connection
Channel 5 created in 0.3 seconds
Getting channel from queue
Returning new channel
Returning Connection
Channel 6 created in 0.2 seconds
Getting channel from queue
Returning new channel
Returning Connection
Channel 7 created in 0.2 seconds
Getting channel from queue
Returning new channel
Returning Connection
Channel 8 created in 0.3 seconds
Getting channel from queue
Returning new channel
Returning Connection
Channel 9 created in 0.3 seconds
Getting channel from queue
Waiting for queue...
Putting channel back on queue
Getting channel from queue
Waiting for queue...
Putting channel back on queue
Getting channel from queue
Waiting for queue...
Putting channel back on queue
Getting channel from queue
Waiting for queue...
Putting channel back on queue
Getting channel from queue
Waiting for queue...
Putting channel back on queue
Getting channel from queue
Waiting for queue...
Putting channel back on queue
Getting channel from queue
Waiting for queue...
Putting channel back on queue
Getting channel from queue
Waiting for queue...
Putting channel back on queue
Getting channel from queue
Waiting for queue...
Putting channel back on queue
Getting channel from queue
Waiting for queue...
Putting channel back on queue
Getting channel from queue
Waiting for queue...
Putting channel back on queue
Putting channel back on queue
Putting channel back on queue
Putting channel back on queue
Putting channel back on queue
Putting channel back on queue
Putting channel back on queue
Putting channel back on queue
Putting channel back on queue
Putting channel back on queue
```

Comment: >"which they recommend to do"


Where did you read it?

You don't need a pool just create a channel per thread/context.

for example 1 channel per thread/producer and 1 channel for thread consumer.

you can leave the channel open.

Comment: Hi Gabriele This text "Given both of these factors, limiting the number of channels used per connection is highly recommended. As a rule of thumb, most applications can use a single digit number of channels per connection. Those with particularly high concurrency rates (usually such applications are consumers) can start with one channel per thread/process/coroutine and switch to channel pooling when metrics suggest that the original model is no longer sustainable, e.g. because it consumes too much memory." here https://www.rabbitmq.com/channels.html

Comment: Also here "Just like connections, channels are meant to be long-lived. Opening a new channel for every operation would be highly inefficient and is highly discouraged. Channels, however, can have a shorter life span than connections. For example, certain protocol errors will automatically close channels. If applications can recover from them, they can open a new channel and retry the operation." https://www.rabbitmq.com/dotnet-api-guide.html

Comment: After asking the question on the rabbitmq google group It sounds like I need to investigate https://masstransit-project.com/ which sounds then like I dont have to worry as much

Comment: This kind of optimization is needed only when you have a very high number of connections and channel. Btw if you found the solution is ok

Answer (score 0):

I decided to stop the work there and look into MassTransit as sounds like this can handle this stuff for me https://masstransit-project.com/